# Keywords dictionary

Tags: dictionary, keyword

I developed a web site to search a database of videos indexed by keywords.
There are several keywords that are repeated like "kid" and "kids" or "children"

I'd like that when users search for a keyword they will find also videos with similar keywords and keywords translation (ex. "kid" > "kinder").

I was thinking about using an external dictionary, there's Google dictionary but it does not provide APIs.

Have you got any idea on how can I do that?

Thanks

Giuseppe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) provides a free-to-use (even commercially) dictionary containing synonyms.

For instance, the "[kid](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=kid&sub=Search+WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o7=&o5=&o1=1&o6=&o4=&o3=&h=)" word contains the following synset:

> Noun
>
> - S: (n) child, kid, youngster, minor, shaver, nipper, small fry,
>     tiddler, tike, tyke, fry, nestling (a
>     young person of either sex) "she
>     writes books for children"; "they're
>     just kids"; "`tiddler' is a British
>     term for youngster"

See [this page for libraries to access the dictionary](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/related-projects/#local) from the language your program is in.

Comment: any suggestion for language translators?
english-italian and italian-english is what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm not aware of any off-the-shelf or open source ones - you might be able to find a raw english-to-italian dictionary which you could use for single words.  You might also look at Google Translate - they offer an API to use their translation functionality in other programs http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/